# How to parse instance id in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

We want to get away from using incremental numbers for the host names of our instances. These machines are not in an auto-scaling group, hence we could keep the `prod-webserver-001`, `prod-webserver-002` etc convention if we wanted but it just doesn't make sense with tags being available.

What we've been doing with auto-scaling groups, we want to utilize parts of the instance id. I'm able to accomplish this with a post script with our ASG servers but unlike that, I want Terraform to keep track of the DNS record so that they get destroyed when I issue a `terraform destroy`.

Ideally we want the first six characters after the hyphen in the `instance_id`. For example if the `instance_id` is `i-0876cr2456` we want to use `0876cr` within the name.

```
prod-webserver-0876cr
prod-webserver-09a24i
```

Terraform code:

```
resource "aws_instance" "instance" {
  ...
  ...
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "instance_dns_a" {
  count   = "${var.num_instances}"
  zone_id = "${var.internal_zone_id}"

# New line but we want the parsed version
  name    = "${aws_instance.instance.id}"

# old that works
  name    = "${format(prod-${service_name}-%03d", count.index + 1)}"
}
```

Comment: Just be aware that longer instance IDs are coming and may want to factor this into your design decision.

Comment: Relevant: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080627-00/?p=21823

Answer (score 1):

You could extract the first 6 characters from the instance id by using [`substr`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html#substr-string-offset-length-):

```
$ terraform console
> substr("i-123456adgcgabsadh", 2, 6)
123456
```

So to use it in your Route53 record you'd want to use something like:

```
resource "aws_instance" "instance" {
  ...
  ...
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "instance_dns_a" {
  count   = "${var.num_instances}"
  zone_id = "${var.internal_zone_id}"

  name    = "prod-${var.service_name}-${substr(aws_instance.instance.*.id[count.index], 2, 6}"
}
```

I would be worried about truncating the instance ID for something that needs to be unique though because you will then inevitably end up with instances with ids of `i-123456a...` and `i-123456b` and then you'll end up overwriting the `prod-webserver-123456` record with the IP address of the second instance and losing the first record. Any reason you need to truncate here? You have 63 characters to play with for the first label in DNS which should be enough to leave this untruncated no?

Comment: We're using it as part of the hostnames so the "shorter" the better, I think? I know for the most part we would be copying and pasting but I still wouldn't feel comfortable with a super duper long hostname but I know what you're saying.

Comment: I don't really know how you're working so don't understand the issue with long host names but I'd definitely be more worried about causing a clash on a unique id because you're truncating the id.